# greens function for one point boundary problem

Tags: boundary-value-problem, greens-function, greens-theorem

How do you find the greens function for the one point BVP?

$y'' + 7y' + 6y = f(t)$, where $y(0) = y'(0) = 0$

Comment: You want to find a solution that is zero for $t<0$, and satisfies $ Ly= \delta(t-\tau) $, $L$ being the differential operator on the LHS of your equation. Can you manage that?

Comment: So the LHS satisfies [\frac{d^2}{dt^2} + 5 \frac{d}{dt} + 6 ]y=δ(t−τ), where that is the dirac delta function. @Chappers

Comment: Yes. You need to explain what precisely you're having a problem with if we're going to be able to help you.

Comment: I think in this problem the given information is incomplete. When I am going to solve this question I feel that there is something missing. So please provide the complete information.. @ jwshua